# If inside for-each-loop to Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to put following code into streams:

```
            for (Engine engine : engines) {
                if (engine.getId().equals(rollingStockId)) {
                    return engine;
                }
            }
            for (TrainSet trainSet : trainSets) {
                if (trainSet.getId().equals(rollingStockId)) {
                    return trainSet;
                }
            }
            throw new LogicException("there is no train-set or engine with ID "+ rollingStockId);
```

I've tried `return engines.stream().filter(engine -> engine.getId().equals(rollingStockId);` and some other variations but they all didn't work. I am relatively new to the Stream API. Is this even possible or useful to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. First invoke `stream()` and then `filter` **and** then [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) and then [`Optional<T>.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--). Like,

```
return engines.stream()
        .filter(engine -> engine.getId().equals(rollingStockId))
        .findFirst()
        .get(); // <-- but better to return the Optional type.
```

Comment: Or an `orElse(null)` depending on what followed the original `for` loop.

Comment: `get` will throw an exception if no item in the collection matches the condition. That piece of info is missing from the OP. Exception might be expected (but then `orElseThrow()` is more explicit) or `null` could also be a valid return value or maybe even an empty `Engine` instance (`orElseGet(Engine::new)`)

Comment: Thank you. It should return nothing if it doesn't find a match. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I've edited my original question to clarify my problem.

Comment: @DonaldDuck There is an API to perform `orElseThow` instead of `get` in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to return a single item (the first one in this case), you want [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--):

```java
return engines.stream().filter(e -> e.getId().equals(rollingStockId)).findFirst();
```

Note that `findFirst()` will return an `Optional<T>` (`Optional<Engine>` in your sample). If you expect `null` as return value if no matching item was found, add another `orElse(null)` call. But oftentimes it is better to be explicit about the possibility of "missing values" by using the `Optional` type. If you want to construct any other object as fallback value, make yourself comfortable with the `orElseGet` method (which expects a lamdba, so is lazily evaluated)